# Can I customise a @font-face declaration from an external imported CSS from a service like Adobe Fonts?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

It's reasonably common for sites I'm building to use the semibold weight of a given font for their "bold" variant. Usually, this is very easy to set up by using a custom `@font-face` declaration that points at the semibold files and has `font-weight: 700;`.

That's fine when the fonts are available under a free licence, and can be hosted directly alongside the website. Sometimes, however, the fonts I need to use are only available under a paid licence. My employer pays for a subscription to Adobe Fonts to give us access to these fonts.

However, Adobe Fonts sets up its own `@font-face` declarations in the CSS files it provides for a given web project, and for semibold weights it uses the standard `font-weight: 600;`.

Unfortunately I've found very little information online about using `@font-face` with Adobe Fonts (or Typekit, which it used to be called). The closest thing I found on Adobe's own website (https://www.adobe.com/devnet/edge-web-fonts/articles/use-at-font-face-with-with-font-services.html) doesn't say anything about using `@font-face` with Adobe Fonts/Typekit.

I don't trust the file URLs Adobe Fonts uses in its CSS to remain static, so I don't think I can reuse them in my own CSS without risking breaking the fonts once those URLs are no longer correct.

Is there any way in CSS I can do something like create a new `@font-face` declaration based on a previous one created in an imported CSS file, or modify a `@font-face` declaration that was included this way? I'd much rather just set up the font to use its semibold files when the browser thinks it should be bold, instead of telling the browser to use the semibold `font-weight` where it would would normally use bold.

Comment: Why don’t you just stick with the @font-face declarations from Adobe, and then in your own CSS use font-weight 600 instead of font-weight bold?

Comment: In this case, we're also using another font on the website that does use the proper 700 weight for its bold variant, so it could potentially be quite a maintenance headache to ensure the correct (but different) bold weight is used in each context. And being able to use the default bold weight also saves me from having to override default user agent styles setting font weight to "bold" or "bolder".

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this issue, the solution I've gone with for now is to create my own `@font-face` declaration using the URLs from Adobe Fonts' CSS file, but with a different name for the font family.

I'm using the Adobe Fonts font family as a fallback for if the one I've created doesn't load, so if the URLs break it should at least fall back to the one Adobe Fonts has set up with the font weights that don't match what I need.

```
/* Here Adobe Fonts uses @font-face to create the font family "adobe-font" */
@import "https://use.typekit.net/<my-project-key>.css";

@font-face {
    font-family: "Custom Font";
    src: url("https://use.typekit.net/path/to/font/file/regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("https://use.typekit.net/path/to/font/file/regular.woff") format("woff"),
        url("https://use.typekit.net/path/to/font/file/regular.ott") format("opentype");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: auto;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Custom Font";
    src: url("https://use.typekit.net/path/to/font/file/italic.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("https://use.typekit.net/path/to/font/file/italic.woff") format("woff"),
        url("https://use.typekit.net/path/to/font/file/italic.ott") format("opentype");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    font-display: auto;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Custom Font";
    src: url("https://use.typekit.net/path/to/font/file/semibold.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("https://use.typekit.net/path/to/font/file/semibold.woff") format("woff"),
        url("https://use.typekit.net/path/to/font/file/semibold.ott") format("opentype");
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: auto;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Custom Font";
    src: url("https://use.typekit.net/path/to/font/file/semibold-italic.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("https://use.typekit.net/path/to/font/file/semibold-italic.woff") format("woff"),
        url("https://use.typekit.net/path/to/font/file/semibold-italic.ott") format("opentype");
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
    font-display: auto;
}

.my-class {
    font-family: "Custom Font", "adobe-font", sans-serif;
}
```

It's not perfect, but since I haven't been able to find any assurance from Adobe that their font file URLs will never change this at least gives me some security if they do change.